# wordpress queries not working in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code, in the functions.php file is returning nothing, not even hi:

```
...
<?php 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
$qr = new WP_Query(); 
while( $qr -> have_posts() ) {
echo "hi"; $qr -> the_post(); 
echo comments_number('0', '1', '%');
} ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's running at all? Do you get anything output if you move the `echo` to outside your while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$qr = new WP_Query(' '); 
while( $qr->have_posts() ) {
echo "hi"; $qr->the_post(); 
comments_number('0', '1', '%');
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

First, you have to [pass at least something to `WP_Query`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3922). Also, `comments_number` already echoes the result, so you don't need that `echo`there.

Comment: wwhy you moved `wp_reset_postdata` to the end ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales, "Use this function to restore the global $post variable of the main query loop after a secondary query loop using" From the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata), in the first paragraph